# Can I use the word "farm" for a rural/out of city territory with a house, but with no crops or animals on it?

Tags: word-choice

I understand that I may use *"cottage"*, *"cabin"*, *"camp"* for a single house far away from cities, but I am describing a house with a territory, small fence and gates and want to mention it. Is *"farm"* appropriate since there is no farming activity and it is just a rural house?

How can I refer to that? How can I summarize it? Are there better words then the *"farm"*?

Comment: Do you mean an area that would clearly be a farm if it were being used for growing food, but it's not being used for growing food right now?

Comment: I don't think "farm" (or even "smallholding") are suitable terms for a rural property with no associated farming / agricultural activity. Just call it a ***rural property with [attached] land***, same as estate agents in the UK. Maybe in the US you can have a ***ranch*** with no livestock, I dunno. If it's "high-value, long-established" land and buildings, maybe call it a ***country estate***.

Comment: I think that "smallholding" is never used in the US, only in the UK (and perhaps other areas using BrE).

Comment: I've run across the word "smallholding" in the US, but only in an academic context.

Comment: @gotube
Yes, like it was long ago but no more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Merriam-Webster [defines "farm"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/farm) (omitting senses not relevamnt here) as:

> 4 : a tract of land devoted to agricultural purposes
>
> 5a : a plot of land devoted to the raising of animals and especially domestic livestock
>
> 5b : a tract of water reserved for the artificial cultivation of some aquatic life form

I might use "farm" for a house plus adjacent land suitable for rising crops and/or livestock, and formerly employed in doing so. In the not uncommon condition that a house once part of a farm, or suitable for being part of a farm, is no longer associated with such land, it having been sold to become part of another farm, or developed for some other purpose, I might well call the house a "farmhouse". That need not imply that the house is any part of a working farm. A piece of land with buildings that could be a farm but is not being so used could be called a "farmstead" or a "disused farm".

- "Cabin" often suggests a rural vacation home, usually small, not part of a farm.
- "Camp" suggests a place used only for temporary occupancy. There are several different sorts of camp, such as a hunting camp, a children's camp, a music camp, a baseball camp, and so on.
- A "cottage" suggests a relatively small unpretentious but permanently occupied dwelling. It may be in a rural setting, or in a village or town, but not usually in a city or urban location. It may be one or two stories tall, but rarely more.

Comment: I don't think the use of the word "farm" is limited to those uses. If someone says they live on a farm, these days, I don't automatically assume the farm is active. Sometimes it's formerly farmed land that some city dwellers moved into. There's no agriculture happening, but I still call that a farm.

Comment: @gotube People who have lived in the city or inner suburbs may say “farm” as a synonym for “rural property,” but no one actually familiar with farms would do so. A pair of women I worked with once offered to drive me home. Their reaction to seeing a cow at the fence line of my property was priceless. I live in the country. My neighbor had the farm.

Comment: @JeffMorrow Good point. It's worth the OP noting that that use of "farm" may almost only apply to non-rural dwellers.